# LibGDX, Intel MultiOS Engine and Box2D library dependency problems

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, box2d

I'm working on a libGDX (1.9.3) based game, which is working on Android. I use the Intel MultiOS Engine to port the game to iOS. It is possible to get into the menu, but as long as you want to access Box2D-related methods, you get an error and the iOS app is killed. The problem might be a missing library or wrong gradle file, but I'm stuck anyway, because it's not working. The gradle file should contain every dependency that exist. I hope you can help me.

[Github repository](https://github.com/reime005/LibGDXMissileCommand)

**Error/Stack-Trace:**

```
...
art W 13828 415213 /teamcity/workdir/moe_repo_build/moe_repo/art/runtime/native/java_lang_Runtime.cc:65] android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH not found; .so dependencies will not work!
art E 13828 415213 /teamcity/workdir/moe_repo_build/moe_repo/art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:255] No implementation found for long com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.newWorld(float, float, boolean) (tried Java_com_badlogic_gdx_physics_box2d_World_newWorld and Java_com_badlogic_gdx_physics_box2d_World_newWorld__FFZ)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.newWorld(float, float, boolean) (tried Java_com_badlogic_gdx_physics_box2d_World_newWorld and Java_com_badlogic_gdx_physics_box2d_World_newWorld__FFZ)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.newWorld(Native Method)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.<init>(World.java:228)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem - Replace the /Applications/Intel/multi_os_engine/tools/proguard.cfg content with those from /Applications/Intel/multi_os_engine/tools/proguard-full.cfg